# JsonUtil cannot be resolved in WSO2 class mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I am using WSO2 Class mediator to inject String to Jsonbody by using WSO2 Developer Studio.

```
String transformedJson=jsonBody.toString();
        JsonUtil.newJsonPayload(((Axis2MessageContext) context).getAxis2MessageContext(),
                transformedJson, true, true);
```

Facing ERROR like "JsonUtil cannot be resolved" after adding import statement as "import org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil;"

Dependency added in class mediator pom.xml by follows [this](https://itsmeisuru.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/json-support-for-wso2-esb-class-mediator/). Still can't able to resolve this import ERROR.

Dependency File:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.synapse/synapse-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
    <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2-wso2v4</version>
</dependency>
```

Can i get Jar for this? I hope jar name would be "synapse-commons-2.1.2-wso2v4.jar".

Comment: Can you share for which version of the EI you are trying to build the class mediator? The version you are using is pretty old, and I am not sure whether it contains the JsonUtil package in it.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. Can you share the EI / ESB version that you are working with? Also, can you update the mentioned dependency tag including a child element: `<type>pom</type>` and try building?

Comment: Hi @Athiththan
I am using wso2 EI 6.5.0 and developer studio  Kernal version 4.1.0.
I added above mentioned dependency only. Last night tried the same, didn't work for me. today morning i just reopen the developer studio and clean the project, it will auto suggest me to import org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil; Anyway thanks for your effort and valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved above JsonUtil ERROR by adding below dependency in pom.xml

Note: after updating pom.xml, i did mvn update by clicking alt+f5.

dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.synapse/synapse-commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
    <artifactId>synapse-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7-wso2v228</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference Link: [check here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.synapse/synapse-commons?repo=wso2-releases)